# Case-insensitive XML comparison

Tags: .net, xml, uppercase, lowercase

I have unit test solution which basically compare two xmls generated by two diff software.

Issue is one xml has 2 values n lowercase and other has it in upper case like below.

**1st**

```
<IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>
<IsVariable>True</IsVariable>
```

**2nd**

```
<IsMirrored>false</IsMirrored>
<IsVariable>true</IsVariable>
```

I use this method to compare xml:

```
Assert.AreEqual(originalDoc.OuterXml, newDoc.OuterXml);
```

but it returns false when it compare value because of lower and uppercase issue. How would I ignore that case issue and it only compares value?

**EDIT** : One more Issue

Another issue is : if there is an empty element:

1st:

```
<LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>
```

2nd:

```
<LinkedObjectName />
```

If I do Assert.AreEqual, it will do character by character checking and it breaks here.

How I can handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Assert.AreEqual`, use `Assert.IsTrue` and `String.Equals`

```
Assert.IsTrue(
    String.Equals(
        originalDoc.OuterXml, 
        newDoc.OuterXml, 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

**Edit:**

For a more robust comparision of the two XML documents, you can try using the [XML Diff and Patch Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) from Microsoft.  The tool tries to determine if the content of your XML documents is equivalent even in cases where a simple string comparison would fail, such as different ordering of nodes or attributes.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and it's been taking care now. Thanks.

But my issue is still as I found one more thing if there is an empty element:

1st: <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>

2nd: <LinkedObjectName />

If I do Assert.AreEqual, it will do character by character checking and it breaks here.

How I can handle this ?